# The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address, no Idea what is wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, email, smtp

I know that this question already exist, but i read all of them and I did not found answer. This is my SendEmail method.

```
   public bool SendEmail(PostEmail postEmail)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(postEmail.emailTo))
  {
    return false;
  }

  using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
  {
    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
    {
      message.Subject = postEmail.subject == null ? "" : postEmail.subject;
      message.Body = postEmail.body == null ? "" : postEmail.body;
      message.IsBodyHtml = postEmail.isBodyHtml;
      message.To.Add(new MailAddress(postEmail.emailTo));

      try
      {
        smtpClient.Send(message);
        return true;
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
        //Log the exception to DB
        throw new FaultException(exception.Message);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have this error in question

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail
>   address

I have no idea what could be wrong. Please any help ?

Comment: Okay! Your "SendEmail" is not a class!

Comment: the error message couldn't be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a break point on the line

```
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(postEmail.emailTo));
```

and when the debugger hits the line when you run the code
check that value of the email address in
postEmail.emailTo

its most likely in a wrong format and that's what's generating 
the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way of defining client and sending email. The complete structure off defining was wrong, it was not just about emailTo string

namespace App.MYEmailApp.Service
{

public class EmailService : IEmailService
  {

```
public void SendEmail(PostEmail postEmail)
{

  MailAddress from = new MailAddress(postEmail.emailFrom, postEmail.emailFromName);
  MailAddress to = new MailAddress(postEmail.emailTo, postEmail.emailToName);
  MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
  message.Subject = postEmail.subject;
  message.Body = postEmail.body;
  MailAddress bcc = new MailAddress("xxxx@gmail.com");
  message.Bcc.Add(bcc);
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
  //client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  //client.Credentials.GetCredential("smtp.xxxx.com", 587, "server requires authentication");
  Console.WriteLine("Sending an e-mail message to {0} and {1}.", to.DisplayName, message.Bcc.ToString());
  try
  {
    client.Send(message);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateBccTestMessage(): {0}",
                ex.ToString());
  }




}
```

}

public class PostEmail
  {

```
public string emailTo;
public string emailToName;
public string subject;
public string body;
public string emailFrom;
public string emailFromName;
public bool isBodyHtml;
```

}

}